How to initialize an event within a custom control using another custom control
Good day, all
I am trying to create a custom ComboBox. I have created a custom dropdown button and using is as the dropdown button. After the user has pressed this button a panel opens which contains the list of items that can be selected (button format). Once the user selects an item the text of the dropdown button needs to change to the selected item's text. I know this is the basic functionality of a normal windows forms Combobox, but I will be adding some features to this custom combo box which is not available for a normal windows forms Combobox. The problem I have is that the update of the custom dropdown button text only occurs after a have opened the panel containing the available items, close it and open it once again. I am sure I am just simple something simple. Some help will be appreciated.
Please see below for the custom dropdown button code:
namespace Example.CustomControls
{
    public class DropdownCheckBox : CheckBox
    {
        private int initialWidth;

        private string dropdownText;

        private Icon dropdownIcon = Properties.Resources.DropDownArrow;

        public string DropDownText
        {
            get { return dropdownText; }
            set
            {
                dropdownText = value;
                this.Text = value;
            }
        }

        public DropdownCheckBox()
        {
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            Margin = new Padding(0);
            Padding = new Padding(0);
            FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 1;
            FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
            Appearance = Appearance.Button;
            FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = SystemColors.Window;
            FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = SystemColors.Window;
            initialWidth = this.Width;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            Text = dropdownText;
            this.AutoSize = false;
            this.Height = 21;

            Rectangle dropDownIconRectangle = new Rectangle(this.Width - this.Height + 2, 2, this.Height - 4, this.Height - 4);

            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(SystemColors.Control), dropDownIconRectangle);
            
            e.Graphics.DrawIcon(dropdownIcon, dropDownIconRectangle);
        }
    }
}

I inherited from the checkbox control since I am using the state of the button to open and close the panel containing the available item list (button format).
Please see below for the panel code which creates the buttons for the items:
namespace Example.CustomControls
{
    public class ButtonsPanel : Panel
    {
        public bool createState = false;

        public string selectedItemButtonText;

        public string[] itemsList = new string[0];

        public string[] ItemsList
        {
            get { return itemsList; }
            set
            {
                this.Controls.Clear();

                itemsList = value;
                createState = true;

                Refresh();
            }
        }

        public ButtonsPanel()
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            Margin = new Padding(0);
            Padding = new Padding(0);
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
            AutoScroll = true;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            this.Height = 5 * 21;

            if (createState == true)
            {
                foreach (string item in itemsList.Reverse())
                {
                    Button itemButton = new Button
                    {
                        Text = item,
                        Height = 21,
                        Dock = DockStyle.Top,
                        TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft,
                        Margin = new Padding(0),
                        Padding = new Padding(0),
                        FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat,
                        BackColor = SystemColors.Window,
                    };

                    itemButton.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
                    itemButton.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
                    itemButton.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;

                    this.Controls.Add(itemButton);
                }

                foreach (Control itemButton in this.Controls)
                {
                    itemButton.Click += ItemButton_Click;
                }

                createState = false;
            }
        }

        private void ItemButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button itemButton = (Button)sender;

            selectedItemButtonText = itemButton.Text;
        }
    }
}

Please see below for custom combobox code:
namespace Example.CustomControls
{
    public class CustomComboBox : UserControl
    {
        private string dropdownCheckBoxText = "Select Items";

        private string[] dropDownitemsList = new string[0];

        private DropdownCheckBox dropdownCheckBox;

        private ButtonsPanel dropdownPanel;

        public string DropDownButtonText
        {
            get { return dropdownCheckBoxText; }
            set
            {
                dropdownCheckBoxText = value;
                dropdownCheckBox.DropDownText = value;
            }
        }

        public string[] DropDownItemsArray
        {
            get { return dropDownitemsList; }
            set
            {
                dropdownPanel.Controls.Clear();
                
                dropDownitemsList = value;
                dropdownPanel.itemsList = value;
                dropdownPanel.createState = true;

                Refresh();
            }
        }

        public CustomComboBox()
        {
            dropdownCheckBox = new DropdownCheckBox()
            {
                DropDownText = dropdownCheckBoxText,
                Dock = DockStyle.Top
            };

            dropdownPanel = new ButtonsPanel();

            this.Controls.Add(dropdownCheckBox);
            this.Controls.Add(dropdownPanel);

            dropdownPanel.Visible = false;

            dropdownCheckBox.CheckedChanged += DropDownCheckBox_CheckedChanged;
        }

        private void DropDownCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dropdownCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Eina");
                this.Height = dropdownCheckBox.Height + dropdownPanel.Height;

                dropdownPanel.Visible = true;
                dropdownPanel.BringToFront();

                foreach (Button itemButton in dropdownPanel.Controls)
                {
                    itemButton.MouseClick += CustomComboBox_MouseClick;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                this.Height = dropdownCheckBox.Height;

                dropdownPanel.Visible = false;
                dropdownPanel.SendToBack();

                foreach (Button itemButton in dropdownPanel.Controls)
                {
                    itemButton.MouseClick -= CustomComboBox_MouseClick;
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            if (dropdownCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                this.Height = dropdownCheckBox.Height + dropdownPanel.Height;
            }

            else
            {
                this.Height = dropdownCheckBox.Height;
            }
        }

        private void CustomComboBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            dropdownCheckBoxText = dropdownPanel.selectedItemButtonText; ;
            dropdownCheckBox.DropDownText = dropdownPanel.selectedItemButtonText;
        }
    }
}

From what I can see is that initially there is 0 controls reported when I created the "CustomComboBox_MouseClick" event, but I am not sure why.

This is a sincere question so I hope it doesn't sound snarky: Are you having success in using the OnPaint override in this manner? It doesn't really seem consistent with the intent of this method, but maybe you know something I don't.

@IV. Nope, it's something you know :) This code requires heavy refactoring (means rebuilding, from the ground up)

@JCB on that note, here's something to consider.  In my personal experience, I've found that it can be way less painful (compared to any kind of custom draw)  to start by inheriting TableLayoutPanel instead of ComboBox (or any other control), and when the time comes to make the drop down visible, show a top level borderless form with a docked FlowLayoutPanel that can contain "anything under the sun", making sure it tracks any movement of the TopLevelForm while it's visible.

@IV, I had the feeling that I was making life for myself a bit to difficult. Therefore I did what Jimi said and started my design from scratch. Sort it out quite quickly. Yet, it was a learning curve for me. My new code is below. I didn't add fields that you could change under the "Misc" portion of the control properties window as was the case for the code I posted when explaining my problem. You will also have to create the control programmatically, but that is all I really needed for my full application that I am working on.

Also, I put everything in one custom control. @IV I hope the below code is sort of what you meant. However, it does work quite well.

I will mark it as the accepted answer based on your feedback Jimi and IV. Maybe you have some extra pointers.

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public class CustomComboBox : FlowLayoutPanel
    {
        private CheckBox dropDownButton;

        private FlowLayoutPanel dropDownFlowLayoutPanel;

        private Button itemButton;

        private Icon dropdownIcon = Properties.Resources.DropDownArrow;

        public CustomComboBox(string initialDropDownButtonText, string[] itemsList)
        {
            dropDownButton = new CheckBox
            {
                Text = initialDropDownButtonText,
                Height = 23,
                Margin = new Padding(1, 1, 1, 0),
                Appearance = Appearance.Button,
                FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat,
                TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft,
                BackColor = SystemColors.Window
            };

            dropDownButton.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = SystemColors.Window;
            dropDownButton.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = SystemColors.Window;
            dropDownButton.FlatAppearance.CheckedBackColor = SystemColors.Window;

            dropDownButton.Paint += DropDownButton_Paint;

            dropDownFlowLayoutPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel
            {
                Height = 10 * dropDownButton.Height,
                BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
                Margin = new Padding(1, 0, 1, 1),
                BackColor = SystemColors.Window,
                AutoScroll = true
            };

            foreach (string item in itemsList)
            {
                itemButton = new Button
                {
                    Text = item,
                    Height = 23,
                    Width = dropDownFlowLayoutPanel.Width,
                    Margin = new Padding(0),
                    FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat,
                    TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft,
                    BackColor = SystemColors.Window
                };

                itemButton.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;

                itemButton.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
                itemButton.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;

                dropDownFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(itemButton);
            }

            foreach (Button button in dropDownFlowLayoutPanel.Controls)
            {
                button.Click += Button_Click;
            }

            this.Controls.Add(dropDownButton);
            this.Controls.Add(dropDownFlowLayoutPanel);

            dropDownButton.CheckedChanged += DropDownButton_CheckedChanged;
        }

        private void DropDownButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dropDownButton.Checked)
            {
                this.Height = dropDownButton.Height + dropDownFlowLayoutPanel.Height + 2;
            }

            else
            {
                this.Height = dropDownButton.Height + 1;
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button clickedItem = (Button)sender;

            dropDownButton.Text = clickedItem.Text;
        }

        private void DropDownButton_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle dropDownButtonIconRectangle = new Rectangle(dropDownButton.Width - dropDownButton.Height + 2, 2, dropDownButton.Height - 4, dropDownButton.Height - 4);

            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(SystemColors.Control), dropDownButtonIconRectangle);

            e.Graphics.DrawIcon(dropdownIcon, dropDownButtonIconRectangle);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            dropDownButton.Width = this.Width - 2;
            dropDownFlowLayoutPanel.Width = this.Width - 2;

            if (dropDownButton.Checked)
            {
                this.Height = dropDownButton.Height + dropDownFlowLayoutPanel.Height + 1;
            }

            else
            {
                this.Height = dropDownButton.Height + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

Your comment says:

...based on your feedback Jimi and IV. Maybe you have some extra pointers.

With that in mind, reading through the answer that you posted, it doesn't really capture my particular feedback of using a top level borderless form as a custom drop list for your combo box. So, I hoped that by laying out a basic implementation below maybe I could clarify what my suggestion would look like in code and on screen.

Sometimes we go to great lengths to do custom draws and such on ComboBox, trying to teach the proverbial pig to sing (which wastes your time and annoys the pig). In my own experience, it can be less painful to start from scratch, inheriting TableLayoutPanel instead of ComboBox (or any other control), and when the time comes to make the drop down visible, show a top level borderless Form containing a docked FlowLayoutPanel that in turn can hold "anything under the sun", making sure it tracks any movement of the TopLevelForm while it's visible.

The first thing our new control is going to need is an Items collection.
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public BindingList<Item> Items { get; } = new BindingList<Item>();

Since the stated goal is adding some features, make a custom item that supports the functionality you intend. In this example, one such feature is individual drop down items that can be styled with ForeColor and BackColor, and can display with either a Button appearance or a CheckBox appearance.
public class Item
{
    public static implicit operator Item(string text) =>
        new Item { Text = text };
    public string Text { get; set; } = "Item";

    [Category("Appearance")]
    public Color BackColor { get; set; } = Color.White;

    [Category("Appearance")]
    public Color ForeColor { get; set; } = Color.Black;

    [Category("Style")]
    public ControlStyle ControlStyle { get; set; } = ControlStyle.Button;

    [Browsable(false)]
    internal CheckBox? Control { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => Text;
}

Having a collection of items provides a more flexible alternative to the constructor you show in your answer:
public CustomComboBox(string initialDropDownButtonText, string[] itemsList){ ... }

Now, by exposing both the Items collection and perhaps a PlaceholderText property for when a selection has not been made, there are multiple ways to edit the items:

Add the styled drop down items in the Designer so that they're compiled in.
Modify the Items collection programmatically at runtime in the code.
Provide the user with an interface to add or remove items dynamically at runtime.

In the Designer

At runtime


Here's how to "show a top-level borderless form..."
I had commented:

Start by inheriting TableLayoutPanel instead of ComboBox (or any other control), and when the time comes to make the drop down visible, show a top level borderless form with a docked FlowLayoutPanel that can contain "anything under the sun", making sure it tracks any movement of the TopLevelForm while it's visible.

Here's what a basic implementation of that comment looks like:
public class CustomDropDownListFromScratch : TableLayoutPanel, IMessageFilter
{
    public CustomDropDownListFromScratch()
    {
        AutoSize = true;
        Items.ListChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            CheckBox checkBox;
            Item item;
            switch (e.ListChangedType)
            {
                case ListChangedType.ItemAdded:
                    item = Items[e.NewIndex];
                    checkBox = new CheckBox
                    {
                        Text = item.Text,
                        Height = 80,
                        BackColor = item.BackColor,
                        ForeColor = item.ForeColor,
                        Appearance =
                            item.ControlStyle == ControlStyle.Checkbox ?
                            Appearance.Normal :
                            Appearance.Button,
                    };
                    checkBox.MouseDown += Any_ControlClick;
                    _flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(checkBox);
                    item.Control = checkBox;
                    break;
                case ListChangedType.ItemDeleted:
                    item = Items[e.OldIndex];
                    if(item.Control is Control control)
                    {
                        control.MouseDown -= Any_ControlClick;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        };
        _dropDownContainer.Controls.Add(_flowLayoutPanel);
        _dropDownContainer.VisibleChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (_dropDownContainer.Visible)
            {
                _dropDownContainer.Width = Width;
                foreach (var control in _flowLayoutPanel.Controls.OfType<Control>())
                {
                    control.Width = Width;
                }
            }
        };
        _dropDownContainer.FormClosing += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // Don't allow the drop down window to dispose!
            if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                _dropDownContainer.Hide();
            }
        };
        _buttonDropDown.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            _dropDownContainer.Location = PointToScreen(new Point(0, this.Height));
            if(!_dropDownContainer.Visible) _dropDownContainer.Show(this);
        };
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        Disposed += (sender, e) =>Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
    }
    
    private Form _dropDownContainer = new Form
    {
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
        TopLevel = true,
        MinimumSize = new Size(0, 80),
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
        BackColor= Color.White,
        AutoSize = true,
        AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
    };
    FlowLayoutPanel _flowLayoutPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel
    {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        AutoSize = true,
        AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink,
        FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown,
    };
    .
    .
    .
}


Full Example
My comment below provides a link to my GitHub repo where you can Browse or Clone how I added my extra features.

Style drop down items with ForeColor and BackColor
Display as either a Button appearance or a CheckBox appearance.
Add or Remove styled items at runtime, with a custom PropertyGrid to edit new items.
Make the dropdown, if visible, track movement of its parent form.
Close the dropdown if [Escape] key is pressed, or if mouse is clicked "anywhere else".
Toggle a checkbox without closing the dropdown.
Toggle between Button appearance and CheckBox appearance at runtime using [Control] + Click.
Reset to PlaceholderText if dynamic item removal makes it invalid.


Clone
